# Mule smpt transport on EC2

Tags: smtp, mule

A Mule flow I have deployed to EC2 cannot send emails to a nodejs "simplesmtp" server running on another EC2 instance. Here are the authentication details for the SMPT server

```
user: joseph
pass: josephk
port: 2525 (open in security group)
```

I can send emails to this SMTP server using various clients on other hosts, here's the auth part of a nodejs client:

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
   host: 'ec2-54-211-220-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
   secureConnection: false,
   port: 2525,
   auth: {
       user: "joseph",
       pass: "joseph12"
   }
});
```

My Mule smpt endpoint looks like this

```
<smtp:outbound-endpoint
    host="ec2-54-211-220-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
    port="2525"
    user="joseph"
    password="joseph12"
    to="cleardot@aol.com"
    from="joseph@ec2-54-211-220-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
    subject="Email from Mule ESB"
    doc:name="send notification"
/>
```

My log error is (I hate dumping log files on here but in this case have to)

```
INFO  2014-11-02 12:03:08,734 [[q2].connector.smtp.mule.default.dispatcher.01]       org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting:  'connector.smtp.mule.default.dispatcher.1535039248'. Object is: SmtpMessageDispatcher
ERROR 2014-11-02 12:03:08,815 [[q2].connector.smtp.mule.default.dispatcher.01]  org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint:      DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=smtp://joseph:<password>@ec2-54-211-220-210.compute-   1.amazonaws.com, connector=SmtpConnector
{
  name=connector.smtp.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=54d8fd1a
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[smtp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
 ,  name='endpoint.smtp.joseph.compute.1.amazonaws.com.2525', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={toAddresses=cleardot@aol.com, subject=Email from Mule ESB, fromAddress=joseph@ec2-54-211-220-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: MimeMessage
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. 530 5.5.1 Authentication Required
  (com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException)
  com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport:1829 (null)
2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=smtp://joseph:<password>@ec2-54-211-220-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com, connector=SmtpConnector
{
  name=connector.smtp.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=54d8fd1a
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[smtp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.smtp.joseph.compute.1.amazonaws.com.2525', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={toAddresses=cleardot@aol.com, subject=Email from Mule ESB, fromAddress=joseph@ec2-54-211-220-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: MimeMessage (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher:117 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.5.1 Authentication Required
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1829)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1368)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:886)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
INFO  2014-11-02 12:03:09,697 [[q2].processArcMessage.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: send alert [B@3c32fb80
ERROR 2014-11-02 12:03:09,706 [[q2].connector.smtp.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
```

Other comments:

I tried using joseph@ec2-54-211-220-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com as the user param with no luck.

Am wondering if Mule smpt requires that I use a standard port, or if I must use smpts not smpt.

My SMPT server logs attempts at authentication but sees nothing coming from Mule

Any help appreciated on this and the general issue of sending email from Mule on EC2

Comment: There's a problem with your security group because I can `telnet ec2-54-211-220-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com 2525`. I reckon you intended to open this port to your instances only...

Answer (score 0):

Clearly Mule can connect to your server because its response is visible in the logs:

```
530 5.5.1 Authentication Required
```

While your server was open to the web (see my comment above), I've noticed that it issued a `250 STARTTLS` so I'm thinking that you should probably use the SMTPS transport for Mule, instead of the SMTP one in order to have proper support for TLS.

Comment: David thanks. I deliberately left that host open to the web but it appears my Node SMTP server crashed. The Mule smtps endpoint returned "Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? (javax.net.ssl.SSLException)" and telnet gave me "220 ip-10-181-241-225 ESMTP node.js simplesmtp". Rather than dig myself further into the ditches of SMTP programming I'll try using Amazon SES as my Mule endpoint. That should be a common setup.